# Is "I have made mung beans sprouts" sentence correct?

Tags: word-usage, present-perfect, grammaticality-in-context

I was kept mung beans to make sprouts, Now sprouts formed. If I want tell this to someone, which sentence is appropriate to use.

Is below mentioned sentences are correct?

> 1. I have made mung beans sprouts.
> 2. I made mung beans to sprout.
> 3. I kept mung beans in water, I got sprouts.

Comment: #1 sounds like you've cooked a dish of the vegetables. #2 expresses your intent in the same way one might say they made chickens lay eggs - you've helped. Out of the set you presented, #3 expresses your intent best.

Answer (score 2):

> 1)I have made mung beans sprouts.

This is not quite right because it implies that you created in the sprouts in the the way you might say "I baked a cake." = "I made a cake." "To make" is not typically used for growing plants. As @Kace36 said in the comments, "grew" would be more appropriate. Grammar is fine in this one, but usage not quite.

EDIT: @Roger Sinasohn is correct. This is not exactly grammatically correct. This should be "I have made mung beans sprout." (sprout as a verb) or "I have made mung bean sprouts." (sprout as a noun).

> 2)I made mung beens to sprout.

So...spelling of "beans", obviously. Grammatically, infinitive is not use here. "I made mung beans sprout." would be grammatically correct, but still have usage issue above.

> 3)I kept mung beans in water, I got sprouts.

Grammar is fine here. Usage is a little odd. "I put mung beans in water, and they sprouted." would be more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could say "I grew some mung bean sprouts" which I think sounds much more casual and like everyday conversation